# Commutations of pullbacks and coproducts?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits

While unraveling the formalism of descent in basic settings (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743954/some-problems-in-formalizing-the-geometric-idea-behind-descent)), I came across two different kinds of isomorphisms which involve pullbacks and coproducts.

One is $$X\times_U\coprod_iU_i\cong \coprod_i(X\times_UU_i),$$
and the other is $$\coprod_iU_i\times_U\coprod_iU_i\cong \coprod_{ij}U_i\times_UU_j.$$

Intuitively, I'd expect commutation of pullback with coproduct to be something like $$\coprod_iA_i\times_{\coprod_iC_i}\coprod_iB_i\cong \coprod_{i,j,k} A_i \times_{C_j}B_k,$$ but that doesn't seem quite right either.

What is the proper way to state commutation of pullbacks with pushouts, and does the second "equation" hold in the category of topological spaces (the first one does, see [2])? If so, why?

**Related:** [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735758/commutation-of-pullbacks-with-disjoint-unions-in-sites),[[2]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89444/do-disjoint-unions-and-fiber-products-commute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that Top is Cartesian closed (assuming you're using the right Top.) Thus pullback functors have right adjoints and preserve colimits. Since the forgetful functors from the slice categories to Top also have right adjoints, they preserve colimits too, so for instance your first line follows. For the second fact, use this commutativity twice; get $\coprod(U_i\times_U \coprod U_i)$ and then the coproduct of all pairwise pullbacks, as desired. For the third, it's enough to calculate $A\times_{\sqcup C_i} B=\sqcup A\times_{C_i} B$, using that coproducts in Top are disjoint.

Comment: I'll work out the details later and ask if I have problems, but for now, are these "equations" simply not true for all of $\mathsf{Top}$?

Comment: If you're using a convenient category, then they're always true. e.g, compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Why go to the trouble of bringing up cartesian closedness or convenient categories? The isomorphisms in question all basically arise from the fact that coproducts are disjoint unions.

Comment: @ZhenLin just because it's what came to mind first. I only thought about coproducts being disjoint for the last equation.

Comment: @Arrow as Zhen points out you can get all three of these from disjointness of coproducts, so no need to worry about whether the pullback functor is cocontinuous. (That is, this is fine on all of Top.)

Comment: @KevinCarlson does this somehow also make us of universality of coproducts? Could you maybe post a solution?

Comment: This is old, but cartesian closure does not imply that pullback functors have right adjoints. It implies that **product** functors have right adjoints.

Comment: @JonathanSterling Yes of course, thanks for that.